# In IdentityServer3, why are all identity claims excluded from the id_token if an access token is also requested?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I have been looking at the source code for IdentityServer3 while working on a custom implementation. I am having trouble trying to add claims to the id_token. I came across this snippet of code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/93bc6bc9b536146b9e3fa0bed21d77283d07f788/source/Core/ResponseHandling/AuthorizeResponseGenerator.cs#L158):

```
 //From AuthorizeResponseGenerator.cs, method CreateImplicitFlowResponseAsync
 string jwt = null;
 if (responseTypes.Contains(Constants.ResponseTypes.IdToken))
 {
     var tokenRequest = new TokenCreationRequest
     {
           ValidatedRequest = request,
           Subject = request.Subject,
           Client = request.Client,
           Scopes = request.ValidatedScopes.GrantedScopes,

           Nonce = request.Raw.Get(Constants.AuthorizeRequest.Nonce),
           IncludeAllIdentityClaims = !request.AccessTokenRequested, // <---- This line
           AccessTokenToHash = accessTokenValue,
           AuthorizationCodeToHash = authorizationCode
      };
```

Setting the IncludeAllIdentityClaims property in this class affects how claims are added once the flow of the program reaches [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/Default/DefaultClaimsProvider.cs#L63). My question is why is the IncludeAllIdentityClaims property being set off a value that relates to the access_token? I thought the access_token and the claims it can hold is completely unrelated to the id_token and the corresponding claims it holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how the spec is written -- it's to optimize the token size. We have a setting called `AlwaysIncludeInIdToken` on the scope claims to disable this optimization.

Comment: I just figured that out by your comments here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/issues/5 . From what you said that is defined by the OIDC spec. So from what I understand if you are only requesting the id_token then all claims will be requested. Thanks!